# Qt creator include guard pattern

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, include-guards

There's a way in *Qt-Creator* to automatically add a template string while creating a new class?

For instance:

I create the new `class Foo`. The header file auto-generated is

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo{
};

#endif FOO_H
```

What I would:

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_FOO_H
#define SOMETHING_FOO_H

class Foo{
};

#endif SOMETHING_FOO_H
```

Ideally I would like to ***customize it based on the project*** like `PROJECTNAME_FOO_H` or even better `PROJECT_NAMESPACE_FOO_H`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I achieved to generate header guards of the form NAMESPACE_NESTEDNAMESPACE_CLASSNAME_H. I couldn't find anything to get the project name, but in my case it was not a problem as my top level namespace is my project name.

Following the answer of @Alan Birtles, I modified the cpp class wizard. You need to copy the files (`file.cpp`, `file.h`, `wizard.json`) from the QtCreator install directory to your home directory (`$HOME/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/templates/wizards` on Linux and macOS or `%APPDATA%\QtProject\qtcreator\templates\wizards` on Windows, according to the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html#locating-wizards)). Put them in the same subfolders (i.e. `wizards/classes/cpp`).

In `wizard.json`, change the line:

```
{ "key": "GUARD", "value": "%{JS: Cpp.headerGuard('%{HdrFileName}')}" },
```

to:

```
{ "key": "GUARD", "value": "%{JS: Cpp.classToHeaderGuard('%{Class}', '%{JS: Util.suffix('%{HdrFileName}')}')}" },
```

Note that you can add some static text to your liking:

```
{ "key": "GUARD", "value": "RANDOM_TEXT_%{JS: Cpp.classToHeaderGuard('%{Class}', '%{JS: Util.suffix('%{HdrFileName}')}')}_INCLUDED" },
```

The complete files can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/juleswh/aeacc89342bc51b19044cf1e04483357

Hope this helps!

---

I used the following ressources, in case it might be usefull:

- Documentation about qtcreator wizards: https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-wizards.html
- Sources of some functions available from the wizard.json file:

  - https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/coreplugin/corejsextensions.h
  - https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/cppeditor/cpptoolsjsextension.h

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the templates in `share/qtcreator/templates/wizards/classes/cpp`.

On the Mac the path is `qt creator.app/Contents/Resources/templates/wizards/classes/cpp`.

Comment: Ideally I would like to customize it based on the project, like projectname for istance

Comment: @Moia if it's only the include guards you want to change just change them to `#pragma once`, all modern compilers support it.

Comment: The jury is out on whether or not `#pragma once` is generally a good idea.

Comment: @AlanBirtles do you have any suggestion about how to edit the template file to achieve that?

Comment: No idea, i don't know the format of the file, I'm sure you could find the relevant creator source code with a little searching or maybe it's even documented somewhere

Comment: Sorry for reviving an "old" thread. In Windows the files are, starting from the location where you installed QtCreator, in `share\qtcreator\templates\wizards\classes\cpp`. To achieve a default `#pragma once` directive instead of the `#IFNDEF` it's sufficient to open `file.h`, locate the `#IFNDEF %{GUARD} #DEFINE %{GUARD}` and replace it with the pragma. Obviously you should also remove the closing `#endif` at the end of the document. If @AlanBirtles wants to update the description he's welcome :)

Comment: @phagio the question wasn't about pragma once at all

Comment: I think I have mistaken then what were you referring to when you asked "how to edit the template file"...?